# npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT on creating new React project when using npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I have tried `npm clear cache` but still whenever I try to run `npx create-react-app`, I get the following error (I have a good Internet Connection).

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Comment: Can you successfully reach the NPM registry? You could try running `curl --head https://registry.npmjs.org/react-tap-event-plugin/-/react-tap-event-plugin-0.1.7.tgz` to see if you can connect. The error strongly implies something's up with the network connection.

Comment: Yeah! I did but I just figured it out myself. The issue was with the npm version. I just upgraded it to the latest version and it solved my problem. Thanks a lot BTW Sir

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the npm version, I was using. I have used multiple solutions but the solution that worked for me was updating the npm version.

For Windows

```
npm update -g
```

For Mac

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```